Grub First, then Ethics
I am a structure, built with care, 
My base is wide, with much to share. 
Ascend my levels, less you'll find, 
But each step up, fulfillment's aligned.
What am I?

This is

 a pyramid: a structure with a wide base that gets narrower as you go up.

 The last line may be referring to Maslow's hierarchy of needs, a pyramid-shaped diagram where each level contains the human needs that must be fulfilled as prerequisites for the next level.

 The title is referring to the Food Pyramid, and perhaps the Ethics Pyramid.

